# Multiple Shiny apps using the ui to populate the second app

Tags: html, r, shiny

I currently have a app that manages projects. The user sees a list of projects and can select one. They can should (it would be nice) be able to click a run button and have another app open. The parameters stored in the project they selected are populated into the second application. The issue I am having is firing the second application. runApp generates the following.

ui code line:

actionButton("RunProj", "Run"),

Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  Unhandled error in observer: Key / already in use
observeEvent(input$RunProj)

I would like to trigger the second app and pass in the location of the project directory I have looked at parseQueryString and still trying to figure out a way to include that. Maybe via a redirect?

Any suggests would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Rich

Comment: You are trying to build a index page which doesn't need to be run by shiny. I assume the number of projects on your site won't be hundreds of thousands or constantly change overtime. Why don't you just use bootstrap and build a basic html page to organize these info? You may also consider to use `knitrbootstrap` to render a page using markdown if you like the markdown syntax better.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I inherited the code. The ui.R is html and the server.R is standard shiny. The code will create/delete/rename and  run a project. There will never be many projects, but they will be large and all the details about them will be saved to the file system. This will be used as a front end for many different types of analysis and the application that is run (via the run button) will vary by user. When the user clicks run all the details of the prior analysis will be put in place. The user can then run sections of the analysis again or check how things were done before.

Comment: BTW thanks for the knitrbootstrap suggestion if not for this application it looks great for others I need to do..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your intention correctly but here is a few things I think you may want to think about.

1. In one project, if you want to run a few kinds of analyses, you may want to try [`navbarPage`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/navbar-example.html)
2. If there are many different types of analyses, you may want to try [`shinydashboard`](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/)
3. If you know the link to each app and you really want to add those "run" buttons, you can add a button manually in ui.R. I think you can write some codes in server.r to generate the link based on your database.

`tags$a(href="the link to your apps", class= "btn btn-default", "Run App")`